# Undefined reference to -finstrument-functions

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I am trying to trace kernel functions and I am using `-finstrument-functions` to do that, but I get undefined reference errors as below:

```
arch/arm/kernel/elf.c:9: undefined reference to `__cyg_profile_func_enter'
arch/arm/kernel/elf.c:13: undefined reference to `__cyg_profile_func_exit'
arch/arm/kernel/built-in.o: In function `elf_set_personality':
arch/arm/kernel/elf.c:42: undefined reference to `__cyg_profile_func_enter'
arch/arm/kernel/elf.c:75: undefined reference to `__cyg_profile_func_exit'
```

There are many more errors similar to above in `drivers` also.
I have exported the `__cyg_profile_func_enter` and `__cyg_profile_func_exit` symbols, but still I get this error. I use `linux 4.1 kernel` and arm board.

Comment: Have you **defined** the `__cyg_profile_func_enter` and `__cyg_profile_func_exit` functions in your code? If so, where?

Comment: @duskwuff Yes I have defined it in `kernel/trace/myfile.c` ,but I have not declared them as `extern` in these above libraries since there are thousands of them and I cant insert into each one. Is there any way to do it in one `extern` statement and if possible where do I add it?

Comment: `extern` is a **declaration**, but error message `undefined reference` means absence of **definition**. Check that `kernel/trace/myfile.c` is actually compiled, and is compiled **into kernel** (`obj-y`), not as a module (`obj-m`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev In makefile, I have compiled as `obj-(CONFIG_MYCODE)` which is set as y

Comment: Simplify code as much as you can: use plain `obj-y` in a Makefile, define given functions in `kernel/trace/myfile.c` in the simplest form: without macros and `#ifdef`s. Check that your makefile is **actually processed** (config `CONFIG_FUNCTION_TRACER` should be "on"). If nothing helps, post your code in the simplest form.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Is there any way in `-finstrument-functions` option to get the line number of the current function such as `__LINE__` of gcc.

Comment: Line number is not passed to the helper functions. However, knowing function's address, you may get its line with `addr2line` utility.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made the entries of __cyg_profile_func_enter and __cyg_profile_func_exit in the header file as well. If not then pls declare these function in the header file and make sure that module is compiling.