# Adding support for symbol for all kernel modules

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a module which is present in `kernel/trace`,say `module.c` and I have defined one symbol in there which I need to make available to all kernel modules. I have used `EXPORT_SYMBOL(mymodule)` in that module to export it to all modules.But I have not specified `extern type mymodule()` in other modules such as `/lib`,`/net` etc. I am getting thousands of undefined references errors now and I cant manually go and add `extern` to all modules. Is there any way to add one `extern type mymodule()` so that it gets used by all modules. I think we should add it in some `Makefile` but how and where do I add it? I am using `linux 4.1` kernel.

**Error message:**

```
lib/lib.a(klist.o): In function `klist_del':
lib/klist.c:230: undefined reference to `__cyg_profile_func_enter'
lib/klist.c:232: undefined reference to `__cyg_profile_func_exit'
lib/lib.a(klist.o): In function `klist_iter_exit':
lib/klist.c:313: undefined reference to `__cyg_profile_func_enter'
lib/klist.c:318: undefined reference to `__cyg_profile_func_exit'
lib/lib.a(klist.o): In function `klist_remove':
lib/klist.c:240: undefined reference to `__cyg_profile_func_enter'
```

Comment: Did you change lots of places in the kernel tree to reference mymodule() and rebuild the whole kernel?  If so, what about adding the declaration to linux/kernel.h?

Comment: @michaeljt I have changed `Makefile` and rebuilt the whole kernel.

Comment: 1. If a symbol is **not declared** (e.g. with `extern <type> <name>`), then compiler error should be about "**undeclared** symbol". 2. Error message "**Undefined** reference" means that symbol is *declared*, but is **not defined**, e.g. if file `kernel/trace/module.c` isn't compiled at all. So which case is your? Also note, that **kernel core** cannot use symbol defined in **loadable module**: you need to make source files *compiled into kernel* (`obj-y += module.o`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have added to makefile the same thing. Mine is not a module rather a built in

Comment: So which **precise error** you get? Add it to the question post. If it is "undefined reference", try the same I [have suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776363/undefined-reference-to-finstrument-functions#comment70752418_41776363) for other asker.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Is there any changes required in kconfig?

Comment: `Is there any changes required in kconfig?` - Required for **what**? Please, provide precise error you got.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried the method u suggested for other user but still I get the same error message as I have posted above.I get thousands of such messages. `module.o` is not getting created. I have tried the same thing in `linux 3.0` and `3.10` and it worked without any error. I have even checked `.config` file and everything needed is checked as `yes` there.

Comment: So your problem is not with `extern` in *other sources*, but with **compilation of your source**, isn't it? If so, then **edit** your question and describe your **actual problem**. Provide `kernel/trace/Makefile` (how you modify it), provide content of `.config` (its part, which affects on your module's compilation).

Comment: See question 41776363 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776363/undefined-reference-to-finstrument-functions).  Did you add -finstrument-functions to any make file?

Comment: @michaeljt I added  `-finstrument-functions` to only main `Makefile`

Comment: If you can remove that then try, otherwise I suggest this should be marked as a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think extern type is explicitly need to define it.
You only need the below implementation (assuming you have already make the changes in Makefile and Kconfig):

**module.c**

```
return_type module_function(function_args){
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(module_function);
```

**module.h**

```
return_type module_function(function_args);
```

Add the header file e.g. **module.h** in **module.c** and file from where you want to access your module_function.

One more thing you can also try with EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL instead of EXPORT_SYMBOL.

Comment: What do you mean by making changes in Kconfig?

Comment: If you are adding new module; then you need to make the changes in the Kconfig. Otherwise Kconfig changes are not required.